# How to record soundflower from OS X?

Tags: macos, audio

I want to record the build-in sound of my Mac computer without using speakers. I want to record directly the sound of my computer. Tutorials shows me that I must do it in System Preferences, but in system preferences, I cant select the sound of my computer in entry. I can only select a microphone. Any Ideas ? I have only 1 option: use speakers
How to use build-in sound to record sound from my mac ?
Also in audacity I have not "Soundflower" option ...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What version of OS X? What version of sound flower?

Comment: You'll need to have Soundflower downloaded and running to use it. Have you made sure that's happening? If so, can you give us screenshots so we can better understand what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Tracking down the correct forks of this semi-dead project was indeed tricky.

I installed the Kernel Extension from here:
https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases

I installed SoundFlowerBed from this fork:
https://github.com/mLupine/SoundflowerBed/releases

That puts an item in the menu that allows you to set `SoundFlower (2ch)` --> `Built-In Output`, which then makes "SoundFlower" available in QuickTime Player etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into your Adobe applications. I had the same issue, couldn't get rid of soundflower, and started thinking of what apps I had that dealt with audio. I remembered I had Adobe Audition, and uninstalled it. It worked! No more soundflower!    Hoppe this helps